# Aply border using bootstrap border class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap CSS framework.

But unable to find any generic class to apply border. I need to apply border to one of the column, Is it something that is supported by frame work, or does it something that is not included and left to be done custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember to add a border only at the table. Therefore, the easiest way to do this - custom class.